# Алгоритм на равное разделение работы на сотрудников

Tags: python, алгоритм

Недавно на сайте по задачкам-головоломкам для программиста наткнулся на задачу, где на входе через пробел цифры и нужно их разбить на 3 части максимально по ровну, на сколько это возможно.

Есть 3 работника, и нужно распределить сколько кому задач отдать. На входе через пробел идут задачи и оценка их сложности. Нужно распределить так, чтобы все работники отработали по ровну. (Выполнять задачи нужно строго в заданном порядке, паралельно работники не работают)

Например, на входе цифры 1 2 3 4 (максимальное кол-во задач 100). Правильным ответом будет отдать первые две задачи 1+2 первому работнику, 3 задачу второму работнику и 4 последнему. Нельзя отдать второму работнику первую задачу, так как задачи должны выполнятся по порядку, а работают они друг за другом, не параллельно. Также как и нельзя вторую задачу отдать второму работнику, так как тогда первый окажется на легке.

Помогите пожалуйста, отмечено что задача не сложная, а я что-то никак догадаться не могу как её решить. Подскажите, может есть какой-то алгоритм классический?

Я пробовал перебором решить, но и перебором что-то запутался и мне кажется получится очень большое кол-во сценарием. 100 задач можно распределить между 3мя людьми 100^3 разными способами, это если я правильно посчитал, а там ограничение по времени выполнения.

Comment: Сложность перебора будет не куб, а квадрат, так что для 100 задач вполне можно и сбрутфорсить.

Comment: и да, 100^3 это тоже быстро. А вообще можно за линейно решить.

Comment: Что то я условие про выполнение задач строго по порядку не понял. Я его так понимаю, что никакого перебора в принципе нет, потому что первый работник забирает задачи строго по очереди начиная с 1й, пока не будет достигнута примерно треть суммарной сложности задач

Comment: @Mike, да, всё верно. Поэтому даже не понимаю как тут перебрать. Вероятно сложность перебора больше чем 100^3. Это нужно вычислить когда должен закончить первый и второй работники и все эти случаи посмотреть наиболее рациональный из них. А как вычислить рациональный? Минимальная суммарная разница с работником который больше всех делает ? Но тут у меня в голове только массивы и мне кажется памяти не хватит, если каждый кейс записывать в массивы а потом считать сколько какой из кейсов самый норм.

Comment: Вообще задача просит вычислить максимальную суммарную сложность которую огребет один из работников. Может быть это каким-то образом легче вычислить. Но мне кажется без понимания кто из работников сколько на себя возьмёт это точно не вычислить

Comment: @Mike, прекрасно, сейчас попробую написать этот алгоритм. Вот такого я и ждал, всё математически. Хочу и в себе развить этот навык.

Comment: @Mike только в этом случае не работает алгоритм если такие задачи: 1 2 3 100. Получается каждому должна быть сложность 35. Значит по этому алгоритму первый заберет все задачи, второй 100, а третьему ничего не достанется.

Comment: хм, да, все гораздо интереснее чем казалось ... А работников строго 3 ?

Comment: @Mike да, работника строго 3

Comment: Работайте с обоих концов. В 1 2 3 100 первому - 1, последнему - 100, а дальше смотрим, стоит ли двигать границы и куда. Только не говорите, что этот способ не поделит правильно две задачи между тремя работниками :)

Comment: тогда рабочая гипотеза: заводим два курсора, указатели текущего разделения. ставим их скажем так, что бы они были в одном элементе от концов массива. ведем текущие суммы, соответственно в начале 1 работник 1 элемент, 3 - последний, 2 - сумма всех кроме крайних. И вот дальше самое интересное, надо двигать курсоры туда-сюда (думаю что понадобится в обе стороны), корректируем текущие суммы и их сравниваем, в зависимости что больше/меньше меняем направление движения курсора. У меня пока в голове не складывается только условие прекращения работы

Comment: Постановка задачи очень похожа на ту, которая решается Венгерским алгоритмом https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется, сначала нужно задачу сформулировать. И тогда может получиться, что она тривиально решается.

Пусть есть массив чисел x_0, x_2, ..., x_N

Выберем два числа K и L: 0 < K < L < N. Эти числа будут разбиениями для "работников". Первый получит работы с номерами от нуля до K-1, второй с номерами от K до L-1, третий от L до N.

1. Пусть v_1 = x_0 + x_1 + ... + x_{K-1},
2. v_2 = x_K + x_{K+1} + ... + x_{L-1},
3. v_3 = x_L + x_{L+1} + ... + x_N.

Нужно найти K и L такие, чтобы ... И тут встаёт вопрос о формулировке требования *нужно их разбить на 3 части максимально по_ровну, на_сколько это возможно*

Очевидно, что точных равенств `v_1 == v_2 && v_2 == v_3` не будет почти никогда. Нужен какой-то минимизирующий функционал. Навскидку:

- Минимальная сумма отклонений `|v_1 - v_2| + |v_2 - v_3| + |v_3 - v_1|`
- Минимальное отклонение в евклидовой метрике `sqrt(|v_1 - v_2|*|v_1 - v_2| + |v_2 - v_3|*|v_2 - v_3| + |v_3 - v_1|*|v_3 - v_1|)` минимально
- минимаксный критерий `min(max(|v_1 - v_2|, |v_2 - v_3|, |v_3 - v_1|))`

В любом случае эта задача решается в лоб перебором за N*N/2 подборов K и L. Можно оптимизировать, перебирая не всё, а только сдвигая границы, но такой алгоритм нужно будет обосновывать. Переборный не нужно :) он найдёт все варианты и отберёт оптимальный.

Функция перебора ищет пару K,L, минимизирующую функционал от трёх переменных, равных суммам работ каждого из работников.

```py
def brute_force(lst, norm_func):
    # Начальное состояние: все работы выполняет работник №2
    min_norm = norm_func(0, sum(lst), 0)
    result = (0,len(lst))

    for K in range(1,len(lst)-2):
        for L in range(K+1, len(lst)-1):
            v1,v2,v3 = sum(lst[0:K]), sum(lst[K:L]), sum(lst[L:])
            nrm = norm_func(v1,v2,v3)
            if nrm < min_norm:
                print("New candidate: norm, K,L", nrm, K,L)
                min_norm = nrm
                result = (K,L)
    return result

# Вспомогательная функция, печатает назначения работ.
def print_result(test, K,L):
    print((test[0:K], sum(test[0:K])),(test[K:L], sum(test[K:L])),(test[L:], sum(test[L:])))
```

В функцию перебора я добавил отладочную печать, чтобы видеть, как убывает значение минимизируемого функционала

Два функционала для проверки: минимаксный и сумма абсолютных значений

```py
def minimax(v1,v2,v3):
    return max(abs(v1-v2),abs(v2-v3), abs(v3-v1))

def abs_sum(v1,v2,v3):
    return abs(v1-v2)+abs(v2-v3)+abs(v3-v1)
```

Тестовый вектор:

```py
test=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Вариант с минимаксной нормой:

```py
K,L = brute_force(test, minimax)
print_result(test,K,L)
```

Результат:

```
New candidate: norm, K,L 41 1 2
New candidate: norm, K,L 38 1 3
New candidate: norm, K,L 34 1 4
New candidate: norm, K,L 29 1 5
New candidate: norm, K,L 23 1 6
New candidate: norm, K,L 21 2 6
New candidate: norm, K,L 18 3 6
New candidate: norm, K,L 16 3 7
New candidate: norm, K,L 14 4 6
New candidate: norm, K,L 8 4 7
New candidate: norm, K,L 4 5 7
([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 15) ([6, 7], 13) ([8, 9], 17)
```

Вариант с суммой отклонений:

```py
K,L = brute_force(test, abs_sum)
print_result(test,K,L)
```

Результат

```
New candidate: norm, K,L 82 1 2
New candidate: norm, K,L 76 1 3
New candidate: norm, K,L 68 1 4
New candidate: norm, K,L 58 1 5
New candidate: norm, K,L 46 1 6
New candidate: norm, K,L 42 2 6
New candidate: norm, K,L 36 3 6
New candidate: norm, K,L 32 3 7
New candidate: norm, K,L 28 4 6
New candidate: norm, K,L 16 4 7
New candidate: norm, K,L 8 5 7
([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 15) ([6, 7], 13) ([8, 9], 17)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Прекрасный алгоритм, работает действительно лучше. Действительно, алгоритм работает лучше чем у @Mike.

Comment: https://ideone.com/7Rh2VB - Ваш алгоритм https://ideone.com/H2RUXc - @Mike (на больших цифрах перегружает первого работника). Наверняка там можно доработать, спасибо вам ребята, вы очень умные! Данный метод перебора кажется более очевидным и простым для понимания. Думаю у метода Mike нужно просто изменить способ вычисления оптимальных границ и будет также работать.

Answer (score 3):

Алгоритм предложенный в комментариях с плавным сдвиганием границ между работниками до достижения лучшего распределения. Сделал на perl, постарался подробно описать процесс, для удобства перевода на питон.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @DATA;
while(<DATA>) { # Получение входных данных и запуск рабочей процедуры на них
        chomp;
        @DATA = split /\s+/;
        next if @DATA < 3; # Не обрабатываем строки с менее чем 3 элементами
        work();
}

# Основная рабочая процедура, на входе готовые данные в массиве @DATA
# Массивы с разделителями и суммами теоретически позволяют увеличить количество работников
# с минимальными правками алгоритма
sub work {
        # Массив позиций разделителей с дополнительныйми элементами по краям
        # для контроля по ним выходов за границы массива (сокращает количество проверок границ)
        # Содержит начало данных, левый разделитель (после первого элемента),
        # правый разделитель (второй с конца), конец данных
        my $border = [ 0, 1, @DATA-1, @DATA-0 ];
        # Текущие суммы разделенных частей массива, в тех же элементах (по номеру) что и позиции границ
        my $sum = [ 0, $DATA[0], 0, $DATA[$border->[2]] ];
        # Вычисляем сумму элементов средней части (массива без крайних элементов)
        $sum->[2]+=$_ for @DATA[1..$border->[2]-1];
        # Рабочий цикл, боюсь делать while(1)
        for(1..1000) {
                my $ch = change($border, $sum, 1) + # Двигаем левый разделитель
                         change($border, $sum, 2);  # Двигаем правый разделитель
                last unless $ch; # Завершаем цикл если ни одна граница не двигалась
        }
        # Печать результата
        print join('+', @DATA[0..$border->[1]-1]), "=$sum->[1] // ";
        print join('+', @DATA[$border->[1]..$border->[2]-1]), "=$sum->[2] // ";
        print join('+', @DATA[$border->[2]..@DATA-1]), "=$sum->[3]\n";
}

sub change {
        # Движение одного разделителя в сторону "улучшения равномерности сумм"
        # Параметры: Описания границ, Текущие суммы, Номер разделителя
        my($border, $sum, $pos) = @_;
        my $n1 = $sum->[$pos];   # Сумма левее разделителя
        my $n2 = $sum->[$pos+1]; # Сумма правее разделителя
        # Получаем направление движения границы +1 вправо, -1 влево
        # Если суммы одинаковы, направление 0 - выходим
        (my $sign = $n2 <=> $n1) || return 0;
        my $i = $border->[$pos]; # Текущая позиция в массиве данных
        # Выходим если движение в нужную сторону не возможно, так как упираемся в другой разделитель
        return 0 if $border->[$pos+$sign] == $i+$sign;
        my $oldDelta = abs($n1 - $n2);  # Текущая разница сумм
        if($sign > 0) { # движение вправо
                $n1 += $DATA[ $i ];
                $n2 -= $DATA[ $i ];
        } else { # движение влево
                $n1 -= $DATA[ $i-1 ];
                $n2 += $DATA[ $i-1 ];
        }
        my $newDelta = abs($n1 - $n2);  # Новая разность сумм
#       print "pos: $pos [$border->[$pos]],   sign: $sign n1: $n1,  n2: $n2 nD: $newDelta, oD: $oldDelta\n";
        return 0 if $newDelta >= $oldDelta; # Выходим ничего не меняя, если результат не улучшился
        # Движение в выбранную сторону улучшает результат, сохраняем новые суммы и позицию
        $sum->[$pos] = $n1;
        $sum->[$pos+1] = $n2;
        $border->[$pos]+=$sign;
        return 1;
}
__DATA__
1 2 3 100
1 2 3 100 101 102 140
4 4 4 4
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 100 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 200 1 1
```

Пример на [ideone.com](https://ideone.com/bdKwnD)

Comment: Спасибо большое, думаю разбирусь. Тоже думал о неких границах которые нужно двигать, но не понимал как. Сейчас буду пробовать.

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю этот код подойдет:

```
a=[1,2,3,100]
workers=[[] for i in range(3)]
average = sum(a)//len(a)+1

# заполняем 1го работника
while ((sum(workers[0])+a[0])<=average) and (len(a)>2):
    workers[0].append(a[0])
    del a[0]

# если осталось 2 задачи, то раскидываем на остальных
workers[1].append(a[0])
del a[0]

if len(a)==1:
    workers[2].append(a[0])
# если больше 2х задач, то аналогично заполняем 2го работника
else:
    while ((sum(workers[1])+a[0])<=average) and (len(a)>1):
        workers[1].append(a[0])
        del a[0]
    # заполняем 3го работника
    workers[2].extend(a)

print(*workers, end='\n')
```

Comment: на 1,2,3,100, 5, 6, 7 не работает. на 1,2,3,100, 101, 102 так же

Comment: @Mike на примерах, которые вы привели алгоритм работает. Либо объясните в чем проблема.

Comment: Пример https://ideone.com/EjvleU Ничего что у второго работника вообще нет никаких работ ?

Comment: @Mike исправил код.

Comment: 1,2,3,100, 101, 102, 140 второй работник получает только 100. в итоге сумма у третьего 343. А должно быть думаю [1,2,3,100] / [101, 102] / [ 140 ]

Answer (score 0):

Постановка задачи очень похожа на ту, которая решается [Венгерским алгоритмом](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm)

Здесь, реализация на Python

```
https://github.com/tdedecko/hungarian-algorithm/blob/master/hungarian.py
```

Comment: Ничего общего в задаче нет. В условиях задачи ТС порядок выполнения работ строго ограничен. В итоге какой либо перебор вариантов вообще не требуется и решение достижимо максимум на O(2n). А приведенный вами алгоритм рассчитан на произвольное распределение работ между сотрудниками, в итоге и сложность его гораздо выше O(n^3)

Comment: Венгерским алгоритмом эту задачу не решить, т.к. тут нужно последовательное распределение по 1му 2му и 3му работникам, а не выборочное. Однако его можно "допилить" до данной ситуации